# Fail to install alpine linux in sysmode

Tags: pi-2, boot-issues

I have a raspberry pi 2B and I wanted to install alpine linux in sys mode. I use a 64gb microsd samsung evo plus. I followed the wiki of alpine [here](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Classic_install_or_sys_mode_on_Raspberry_Pi) formatting like in troubleshot the boot partition in fat32. However that doesn't seem to work. Something happened to be different in the responses to the commands, `ln -s media/mmcblk0p1/boot boot` is expected to give an error but it didn't gave one and the reboot doesn't takes minutes like it is written in the wiki.

When at the end I reboot there are some errors at boot:

- first the clock `Clock skew detected with '(null)'`
- `Mounting modloop` -> `ERROR: modloop failed to start`
- then I have several `modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': no such file or directory` on

  - starting busybox mdev
  - loading hardware drivers
  - loading modules

You have a photo below, I don't know where to find these logs to copy them as text

[image: alpine boot]

Then, this is the dmesg log:

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0xf00
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.84-0-rpi2 (buildozer@build-3-12-armv7) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Alpine 9.3.0)) #1-Alpine SMP Wed Dec 16 11:38:04 UTC 2020
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fc075] revision 5 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: div instructions available: patching division code
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: Raspberry Pi 2 Model B Rev 1.1
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x37400000, size 64 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node linux,cma, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 242688
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 2133 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 242688 pages, LIFO batch:63
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 20 pages/cpu s49676 r8192 d24052 u81920
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s49676 r8192 d24052 u81920 alloc=20*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 240555
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1680 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=1050 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  modules=loop,squashfs,sd-mod,usb-storage quiet console=tty1
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] Memory: 878344K/970752K available (8192K kernel code, 697K rwdata, 2620K rodata, 1024K init, 819K bss, 26872K reserved, 65536K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] random: get_random_u32 called from __kmem_cache_create+0x38/0x4dc with crng_init=0
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] rcu: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 10 jiffies.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 16, nr_irqs: 16, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.000000] arch_timer: cp15 timer(s) running at 19.20MHz (phys).
[    0.000000] clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x46d987e47, max_idle_ns: 440795202767 ns
[    0.000010] sched_clock: 56 bits at 19MHz, resolution 52ns, wraps every 4398046511078ns
[    0.000023] Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 52ns
[    0.000311] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.000334] printk: console [tty1] enabled
[    0.000391] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 38.40 BogoMIPS (lpj=192000)
[    0.000408] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.000731] LSM: Security Framework initializing
[    0.000999] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)
[    0.001022] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)
[    0.002633] Disabling memory control group subsystem
[    0.002809] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.003447] CPU0: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.003461] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 15, mpidr 80000f00
[    0.004461] Setting up static identity map for 0x100000 - 0x10003c
[    0.004668] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.005382] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.006651] CPU1: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.006663] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 15, mpidr 80000f01
[    0.008021] CPU2: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.008032] CPU2: thread -1, cpu 2, socket 15, mpidr 80000f02
[    0.009289] CPU3: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.009299] CPU3: thread -1, cpu 3, socket 15, mpidr 80000f03
[    0.009445] smp: Brought up 1 node, 4 CPUs
[    0.009458] SMP: Total of 4 processors activated (153.60 BogoMIPS).
[    0.009465] CPU: All CPU(s) started in HYP mode.
[    0.009470] CPU: Virtualization extensions available.
[    0.010671] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.025207] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 2 part 30 variant 7 rev 5
[    0.025887] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.025916] futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.029607] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.032246] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.035488] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.040909] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.041253] audit: type=2000 audit(0.040:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
[    0.044473] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.044485] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 8 bytes.
[    0.044876] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.047498] bcm2835-mbox 3f00b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.070202] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2020-09-02 21:15, variant start
[    0.080196] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Firmware hash is 4439d2aaa6c376a2d1ef4402f142e1cf4de37c43
[    0.173061] bcm2835-dma 3f007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager, dmachans=0x1
[    0.177570] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.178808] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.179024] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.179194] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.183774] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    1.278316] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    1.278448] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    1.278643] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    1.278993] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    1.295208] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
[    1.295795] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    1.296858] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 6144 bytes, linear)
[    1.296905] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
[    1.297034] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    1.297235] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    1.297432] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    1.297498] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    1.297865] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    1.298750] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    1.298760] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    1.298767] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    1.298773] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    1.299167] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[    1.558257] Freeing initrd memory: 3176K
[    1.559412] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a7 PMU driver, 5 counters available
[    1.563574] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    1.564023] workingset: timestamp_bits=14 max_order=18 bucket_order=4
[    1.579045] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    1.579988] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    1.580030] Key type id_resolver registered
[    1.580038] Key type id_legacy registered
[    1.580059] nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
[    1.581713] Key type asymmetric registered
[    1.581726] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    1.581814] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 249)
[    1.581826] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    1.581834] io scheduler kyber registered
[    1.584450] bcm2708_fb soc:fb: FB found 1 display(s)
[    1.617602] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 210x65
[    1.651312] bcm2708_fb soc:fb: Registered framebuffer for display 0, size 1680x1050
[    1.656752] bcm2835-rng 3f104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    1.657178] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3ec00000 mem_size:0x40000000(1024 MiB)
[    1.658173] vc-sm: Videocore shared memory driver
[    1.658755] gpiomem-bcm2835 3f200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0x3f200000
[    1.676821] brd: module loaded
[    1.693093] loop: module loaded
[    1.694870] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    1.696329] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    1.696512] usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
[    1.696632] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.696655] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    2.425013] Core Release: 2.80a
[    2.425030] Setting default values for core params
[    2.425079] Finished setting default values for core params
[    2.625439] Using Buffer DMA mode
[    2.625448] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    2.625454] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    2.625465] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
[    2.625489] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
[    2.626375] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_init:1072: FIQ DMA bounce buffers: virt = b7514000 dma = 0xf7514000 len=9024
[    2.626412] FIQ FSM acceleration enabled for :
[    2.626412] Non-periodic Split Transactions
[    2.626412] Periodic Split Transactions
[    2.626412] High-Speed Isochronous Endpoints
[    2.626412] Interrupt/Control Split Transaction hack enabled
[    2.626421] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
[    2.626486] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:457: FIQ on core 1
[    2.626498] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:458: FIQ ASM at 8069a974 length 36
[    2.626513] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:496: MPHI regs_base at bb810000
[    2.626540] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    2.626589] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    2.626646] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: irq 56, io mem 0x00000000
[    2.626694] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
[    2.626700] Init: Power Port (0)
[    2.627067] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.04
[    2.627081] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.627092] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    2.627103] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.84-0-rpi2 dwc_otg_hcd
[    2.627113] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 3f980000.usb
[    2.628093] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.628221] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    2.629587] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    2.629597] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    2.629603] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
[    2.629727] Module dwc_common_port init
[    2.630260] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    2.630706] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    2.632628] bcm2835-wdt bcm2835-wdt: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
[    2.636583] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    2.636593] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    2.637472] sdhost-bcm2835 3f202000.mmc: could not get clk, deferring probe
[    2.637721] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    2.639313] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    2.640497] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    2.640985] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.640994] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.642237] vchiq: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = (ptrval)
[    2.644276] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[    2.654260] [vc_sm_connected_init]: end - returning 0
[    2.656008] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    2.656191] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    2.656612] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    2.657160] registered taskstats version 1
[    2.657187] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    2.657703] Key type ._fscrypt registered
[    2.657712] Key type .fscrypt registered
[    2.668694] uart-pl011 3f201000.serial: cts_event_workaround enabled
[    2.668835] 3f201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 81, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    2.671055] bcm2835-power bcm2835-power: Broadcom BCM2835 power domains driver
[    2.672607] sdhost: log_buf @ (ptrval) (f7513000)
[    2.720426] mmc0: sdhost-bcm2835 loaded - DMA enabled (>1)
[    2.723266] hctosys: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
[    2.723278] of_cfs_init
[    2.723510] of_cfs_init: OK
[    2.743446] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1024K
[    2.779454] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    2.782024] mmc0: new high speed SDXC card at address 0001
[    2.783246] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 EC2QT 59.6 GiB
[    2.786237]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    2.804149] Run /init as init process
[    2.854080] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[    2.940053] random: fast init done
[    3.064008] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
[    3.064721] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[    3.304616] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9514, bcdDevice= 2.00
[    3.304662] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.306126] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    3.306317] hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
[    3.436006] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    3.436024] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): write access will be enabled during recovery
[    3.623867] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
[    3.636497] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): recovery complete
[    3.661909] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    3.754458] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00, bcdDevice= 2.00
[    3.754483] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.757963] smsc95xx v1.0.6
[    3.849401] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:c7:34:e6
```

Since I followed all the instructions, my questions are: is there something more that I have to do in order to make it work? Did anybody get it work on 2B? I think yes since it is cited in the troubleshot section of the wiki, so I am missing definitely something.

Answer (score 0):

I've got same error after follow this [instruction](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Classic_install_or_sys_mode_on_Raspberry_Pi) with my Raspberry Pi
Model 1B.

After compare with other instructions...

[instruction](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) from another Alpine wiki page for Raspberry Pi:

[image: Compare_1]

[instruction](https://dev.alpinelinux.org/%7Eclandmeter/other/forum.alpinelinux.org/comment/1084.html#comment-1084) from Alpine forum for RPi3:

[image: Compare_2]

I found...
[image: Error]

need to modify command from:

```
sed -i 's/$/root=\/dev\/mmcblk0p2 /' /media/mmcblk0p1/cmdline.txt
```

to:

```
sed -i 's/$/ root=\/dev\/mmcblk0p2 /' /media/mmcblk0p1/cmdline.txt
```

result:
[image: GiveRootSpaceForLiving]